# Creating a pickle file for a machine learning model

Tags: python, nlp, pickle

What i'm trying to do is to load a machine learning model for summary generation in a pickle object so that when i deploy the code to my web app, it doesn't do the manual loading over and over again. That takes quite a bit of time and I can't afford having the user wait for 10-15 min while the model loads and then the summary is generated.

```py
    import cPickle as pickle
    from skip_thoughts import configuration
    from skip_thoughts import encoder_manager
    import en_coref_md

    def load_models():
        VOCAB_FILE = "skip_thoughts_uni/vocab.txt"
        EMBEDDING_MATRIX_FILE = "skip_thoughts_uni/embeddings.npy"
        CHECKPOINT_PATH = "skip_thoughts_uni/model.ckpt-501424"
        encoder = encoder_manager.EncoderManager()
        print "loading skip model"
        encoder.load_model(configuration.model_config(),
            vocabulary_file=VOCAB_FILE,
            embedding_matrix_file=EMBEDDING_MATRIX_FILE,
            checkpoint_path=CHECKPOINT_PATH)
        print "loaded"
        return encoder

    encoder= load_models()
    print "Starting cPickle dumping"
    pickle.dump(encoder, open('/path_to_loaded_model/loaded_model.pkl', "wb"))
    print "pickle.dump executed"
    print "starting cpickle loading"
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open('loaded_model.pkl', 'r'))
    print "pickle load done"
```

cPickle was initially pickle, but none of them did this in enough time. The first time i tried doing this, the pickle file being created was 11.2GB, which is waaay too big i think. And it took well over an hour rendering my pc useless in the meantime. And the code wasn't done executing, i force restarted my pc because it was taking too long.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: have you tried using hdf5?  Here is an example https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Comment: @VnC the models are trained using tensor flow, not keras. So the methods like model_from_json won't work I assume

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check whether storing into hdf5 improves the performance:

Write to hdf5:

```
with h5py.File('model.hdf5', 'w') as f:
    for var in tf.trainable_variables():
        key = var.name.replace('/', ' ')
        value = session.run(var)
        f.create_dataset(key, data=value)
```

Read from hdf5:

```
with h5py.File('model.hdf5', 'r') as f:
    for (name, val) in f.items()
        name = name.replace(' ', '/')
        val = np.array(val)
        session.run(param_setters[name][0], { param_setters[name][1]: val })
```

Sources:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models

https://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com/2018/06/savingloading-tensorflow-model-using.html